# ¿ Cual es la diferencia entre estos métodos de cifrado y descifrado de datos en php?

Tags: php, seguridad, encriptación

en estos momentos estoy adentrándome a dar seguridad a una aplicación web, he visto muchas formas de cifrar datos del usuario y descifrarlo y actualmente utilizo el método de password_hash() con password_verify(), pero veo también el uso de hash_equals() con mcrypt() o hash_mac() y rara vez con password_verify() y eso me genera cierta duda.

¿hash_equals() podría ser equivalente a password_verify()? O se recomienda el uso de esos 2 metodos para verificar los datos.

```
    $opcion = ['cost'=>12, 'salt' => strtr(base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha512", mcrypt_create_iv(20, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM), true)), '+', '.'),];

    $hash = password_hash( $password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, $opcion);
 //envio y después obtengo el cifrado de la base de datos para verificar los datos//
    if (password_verify($password, $passDB)){}....
```

Comment: Este artículo te aclara gran parte (en inglés) las dudas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117732/reasons-why-sha512-is-superior-to-md5

Comment: Si hubiese un método ideal para cifrar y descifrar entonces los demás se eliminarían o aparecerían marcados como _deprecated_. Cada posible solución tiene sus ventajas y sus inconvenientes. Deberías acotar tu pregunta para que las posibles respuestas se puedan basar en parámetros objetivos.